# Receiving blank emails from website

Tags: php, html, forms

I am receiving blank emails from my website every day at 8:15am - 8:19am.
They don't contain any information in them and do not contain the input id's either.

I have gone through multiple forums about this but I am new to PHP and seams to be a bit over my head.

```
    <?php 

function sendFormByEMail($msgBody) {
 $to = "email@gmail.com";
 $subject = "web visitor";
 $from = "email@gmail.com"; 

 $mailHdr = "";
 $mailHdr .= "From: ".$from."\r\n";
 $mailHdr .= "Reply-To: ".$from."\r\n";

 return mail($to, $subject, $msgBody, $mailHdr);
}


function getMessageText() {
 $msgTxt = "";
 $msgTxt .= "Sent: " . date("Y/m/d H:i:s") . "\n";
 foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
 {
   //$msgTxt .= urlencode($key) . "=" . urlencode($value) . "\n";
   $msgTxt .= $key . " = " . $value . "\n";
 }
 return $msgTxt;
}

if (sendFormByEMail(getMessageText())) {
  $nextPage = '../index2.html';
} else {
  $nextPage = '../index2.html';
}

header("Location: $nextPage");

?>
```

HTML

```
<form action="php/formsProcessor.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="quote" id="quote">
    <div class="row">
        <label for="name">Your name:</label><br />
        <input id="name" class="input" name="name" type="text" value="" size="30" /><br />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label for="email">Your email:</label><br />
        <input id="email" class="input" name="email" type="text" value="" size="30" /><br />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label for="message">Your message:</label><br />
        <textarea id="message" class="input" name="message" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><br />
    </div>
    <input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="Send email" />
</form>
```

I have been trying to fix this for a few weeks now and any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a CRON job running? Have you considered addiong some checking to the code to make sure the variables are popoulated?

Comment: what is the problem? that they should not be empty or that they should not be triggered?

Comment: I don't have a CRON running, and i did have a "required" tag on them before but it didn't seem to help.

They are being triggered the same time every day with everything empty,
I hope that explains it

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php and somebody else has a cron job... on you and possibly others. You need to check your access logs and block their sorry asses.

Comment: The CRON would only be running the server-side script *so you must also perform validation on the server-side.* Correction: you must *always* perform server-side validation because, as you can see, client-side validation can be skipped.

Comment: Would I add the validation to the .php form?

Comment: I have been looking on a few websites one in particular is http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp

they have each input separated in the php, Is this something that needs to be done or can i have a overall validation... sorry again new to creating contact forms

Answer (score 0):

Add this text to the header:
"Content-type: text/html charset=iso-8859-1 \r\n"